# Missing Automation from namespace 'System.Management'. Missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

System: Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, PowerShell v 2.0, no Visual Studio (can't be installed and others too)

Trying to run PowerShell from C#. This is the code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;  

class Hello {
    static void Main(string[] args) {           
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
        Console.WriteLine("Process                 Id");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke()) {
            Console.WriteLine(
            "{0,-24}{1}",
            result.Members["ProcessName"].Value,
            result.Members["Id"].Value);
            } 
        }       
    }
```

Error:

> e:\foo.cs(2,25): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Automation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Since no Visual Studio is there, I am running code in raw manner. Because of error, I downloaded dll from `http://www.dll-found.com/system.management.automation.dll_download.html` and placed in dir as per instruction. After rebooting machine, there was no success.

First, I want to ask a general question. How to install missing assembly or dll file (only), because for some you might have to install whole Windows or PowerShell SDK or .NET Framework.

**EDIT**
I have place downloaded dll file in C:\Windows\SysWOW64, C:\Windows\system32, C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 and C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0.

I am compiling using: 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /target:exe /out:E:\foo.exe E:\foo.cs

Comment: did you add reference System.Management.Automation.dll

Comment: How do you compile your file? If you're running `csc.exe` directly, you must specify all references in its command line, not just "copy" dll files to same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `/reference` command line parameter to `csc.exe`, described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /reference:system.management.automation.dll /target:exe /out:E:\foo.exe /E:\foo.cs
```

Comment: Before I accept your answer(it worked), can you comment on two things. Is it good to download dll/files from http://www.dll-found.com? Which paths are commonly searched for reference dll files, so that I can put dll files into that folder only. Or I can put in any drive or folder?

Comment: It is not-so-good for downloading files from there because you may need different versions, processor architectures and so on on a set of files instead of just one file. You need a coherent file versions. Only if you have no idea where these dlls can be from, you can download them from dll-found.com, but you must know that there can be problems in their unmatching public interfaces.

Comment: Thanks kpa6uk for your information. A little Google search revealed answer for second thing.

Comment: Oh I forgot about second question, sorry )

Comment: @msinfo Downloading random DLLs and linking against them is a terrible idea and could lead to getting viruses. Use the official docs to figure out what DLL you need and get it from a trustworthy source. Using sites that distribute random DLLs should never be done in any sane situation.

Answer (score 12):

**WARNING: Never ever download DLLs from random websites in any sane situation. Use NuGet packages (or whatever your preferred package manager is for your project) whenever possible. If a DLL is not found, there is almost always a good reason for it, and you need to find out what it is and fix it, not just get the DLL from the internet.**

If you have this problem after re-targeting an old project to, for example, .NET 4.8, then it is because NuGet package names have changed.

- Uninstall the package `System.Management.Automation`
- Install the package `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies` ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies/1.0.0))

This package name appears in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconfiguration?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) of classes in the namespace `System.Management.Automation`.

Answer (score 9):

NuGet worked for me.

PM> Install-Package System.Management.Automation.dll -Version 10.0.10586